# No command works in Magento 2.x

Tags: magento-2.1, command-line

I used sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade command but get

```
[InvalidArgumentException]                                     
  There are no commands defined in the "deploy:mode" namespace.
```

after that tried list command but get We're sorry, an error occurred. Try clearing the cache and code generation directories. By default, they are: `var/cache, var/di, var/generation, and var/page_cache`.

```
[CredisException]                                                                  
  Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (111) Connection refused
```

Used `rm -rf var/cache var/di var/generation var/page_cache` but still have error. no command works.

Answer (score 0):

Remove redis references from `app/etc/env.php`

They look like this

```
 'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379'
            ],
        ],
        'page_cache' => [
            'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '6379',
                'database' => '1',
                'compress_data' => '0'
            ]
        ]
    ]
],
```